# Random int to .txt file error

Tags: java, random

I would like to know why this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("randomNumbers.txt");
    final int randomNumberCount = 100;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();


    for (int i = randomNumberCount; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    output.print(randomGenerator.nextInt(10) + " ");
    }
    output.close();

  }
}
```

Is giving me a text file with this:

```
‰‹‸‸‹‵‹‴‶′′‴‷″‵‷‴′‶‷‵‹‷′‱″″‸‰‷‸′″‵‹″′‶‶‴‶‴‸′″‹‶‱‱‰‸‸‱‷‶‹‶‶‵‰‹‰‰‹‱‸‷‱‵‶‵‷′‱‵‵‸‸‵‵‱‸‷‸‸‱‸‱‶‱‸″‸′‶″‸‸‷‶′
```

When I change it to pick random numbers of 11 or above, it works.
If I keep it at 10 and make it pick 48 random numbers or lower it works.

What am I missing?

*EDIT*
It will show up correct in Notepad++ but not in Notepad.

Comment: Try `PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("randomNumbers.txt", true); // auto-flush` instead.

Comment: It just worked fine for me, generating integers below 10!

Comment: What text editor are you using to view the file?

Comment: @nhahtdh That did it, I opened it up in Notepad++ and got the right output.

Comment: Now that you found the problem. I'm curious: Did you open this in Windows Notepad? I remember it reading one of my file incorrectly while the content can be normally read in ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, trying A: Specifying the charset to use (I'm guessing notepad doesn't support the default PrintWriter one, only UTF-8). or B: Using different types of OutputStreams, as it appears PrintWriter is using an odd charset, which Notepad doesn't recognize, hence the random funky characters.